# Node.js: CSRF_COOKIE sent by Tobi isn't matching cookieJar

Tags: testing, node.js, browser, csrf

I'm using the [Tobi browser testing tool](https://github.com/LearnBoost/tobi) for node.js.

Tobi seems to be sending a CSRF_COOKIE header that doesn't match anything in the cookieJar.

I'm positing a form using Tobi's submit() that fails CSRF verification (a regular desktop browser works fine). 
The issue seems to be a difference between the form cookie and the HTTP Header.

```
console.log(browser.cookieJar.cookies)
```

Gives:

```
[ { str: 'csrftoken=8a09c3f0b62939458018f74020c6744e; expires=Thu, 14-Feb-2013 15:26:31 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/',
    name: 'csrftoken',
    csrftoken: '8a09c3f0b62939458018f74020c6744e',
    expires: Thu, 14 Feb 2013 15:26:31 GMT,
    'Max-Age': '31449600',
    Path: '/',
    value: '8a09c3f0b62939458018f74020c6744e' },
  { str: 'sessionid=d82a0a4a691481df3fb72b8f3b9e4d8a; expires=Thu, 01-Mar-2012 15:26:31 GMT; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/',
    name: 'sessionid',
    sessionid: 'd82a0a4a691481df3fb72b8f3b9e4d8a',
    expires: Thu, 01 Mar 2012 15:26:31 GMT,
    'Max-Age': '1209600',
    Path: '/',
    value: 'd82a0a4a691481df3fb72b8f3b9e4d8a' } ]
```

The second value matches the csrfmiddleware form on the page.

However, my server received the following from Tobi's browser in its HTTP headers:

```
'CSRF_COOKIE': '347767c1a4baef48ab0272ca6ccfdf5f'
```

Where did the CSRF_COOKIE value come from (or more to the point, why can't I see it in cookieJar?) How can I make the CSRF_COOKIE value correct?